# How to integration with PhoneGap to blackberry java application through BrowserFiled?

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I have a requirement, which need integration with phonegap as 3rd JavaScript library to blackberry java application, is there anyway to do it? My app need to integration with some java native UI component without used HTML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use phone gap in the blackberry project you have to look at here ....

[GET STARTED GUIDE](http://phonegap.com/start/#blackberry).

Also see this [phone Gap slide show](http://www.phonegap.com/HTMLPresentations/PhoneGapBlackBerry/slideshow.html#%281%29).

And this is also a good link to start with [Phone Gap Getting Started with PhoneGap(BlackBerry)](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494777/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20%28BlackBerry%29).

I think this will Help you .

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. But I am confused with webwork and blackberry JDE, you know the phonegap integration with blackberry need used widget SDK to build and packaged. But current for me, we need used JDE to build and package, without config.xml and any HTML in my java application, is there anyway to do that?